# Why does git merge use the octopus strategy?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I created a new `feature` branch from `develop` and made some file changes. I swapped back by checking out `develop` and committed a quick fix to an unrelated file (not modified in the `feature` branch). I swapped back by checking out `feature` then pulled `develop` to apply the fix.

```
Trying simple merge with develop
Merge made by the 'octopus' strategy.
 path/to/file | 6 +++---
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

Why would Git choose to use the octopus strategy? I have never seen it before, have I accidentally tangled branches or done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had accidentally committed my `feature` branch changes to `develop` while swapping between them. When merging `develop` back into `feature` Git had to figure that out while applying my other changes.

So yes a different merge strategy was required, and yes it was a warning that something was afoot!